# 'A' and CNAME Records for Add-on domains

Tags: domain-name-system, godaddy

I have my websites on GoDaddy

Changing DNS records for my primary domain is easy and straightforward.
But the option to do so for Addon Domains is elusive. I am unable to find it.

Is there a way to change DNS records for my Addon Domains on GoDaddy?
Do I need to used SSH for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a question you clearly should ask the goDaddy Support.

A Records are for Ip Adresses and CNAME Records are for aliases. If you can use SSH and if goDaddy supports fiddling with the resource records I would utilise the nslookup tool. This will get you started.

```
nslookup
set type=ns
yourdomain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

If the addon domain is a 'folder' in your main domain (ie  maindomain.com/addondomain) then you can just make that folder in your maindomain site and add an html document that redirects to where you want to go.  All you need is an html document in a folder with the same name as your addon domain with this bit of code in it:

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://www.yourdomain.com/index.html">
```

Comment: Well, the addon domain has to be in a subfolder of my parent website's webroot. But I need its files to be there and not get redirected. Plus do subdomain redirections work the same way as A and CNAME records? i guess not. :)

Comment: If you aren't doing any redirects then you should be fine.  Just put your files in your subfolder of your parent website.  If you aren't referencing the exact file make sure you name your file index.html or setup the default page.